# How to use LSTM with Universal Sentence Encoding in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am trying to train a model by getting encodings from Universal Sentence Encoder and train it with LSTM. Here is my code:

```
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3"
embed = hub.Module(module_url, trainable=True)

def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    embeds = embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))
    return embeds

input_text = Input(shape=(num_sentences,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(None,512))(input_text)
lstm = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(embedding)
dense = Dense(256, activation="relu")(lstm )
pred = Dense(num_classes,  activation='softmax')(dense)
model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
model.compile(Adam(3e-4), loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=["accuracy", "categorical_accuracy", "top_k_categorical_accuracy"])
```

I am getting following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 512)
```

Issue is USE return 2-d tensor with shape (None, 512) and LSTM expects 3-d tensor to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` just before the LSTM to expand the dimensions by 1. reference - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape